# Areca Palm splaying outwards?

Tags: plant-care, palm

Looking for some advice on my Areca Palm. I've had it about 18months, and it's been growing upright quite happily. I needed to move it while I did some renovation work on my house, and since it has started to "droop" or splay out.

What could cause this? And how could I go about rectifying it? Thanks!!